# How to add multiple custom domain to Azure Storage Account hosting static website?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-storage-account

Does anyone know how to add multiple domains to Azure Storage Account static website hosting?

For example, Azure only accepts one or the other www.domain.com and domain.com. Currently, one or the other domain name works fine with the DNS CNAME record but only with one.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean enabling multiple custom domains for a single storage account?

Answer (score 4):

The workaround would be to [map Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal#map-a-custom-domain-with-https-enabled) to your Storage Account. This also gives you HTTPS support, which is what you should want anyways. You can then map multiple custom domains to the CDN.

Comment: Nowadays people using cloudflare a lot, which means the endpoint of azure must be http, because cloudflare does HTTP themselves.

Answer (score 0):

> How to add multiple custom domain to Azure Storage Account hosting static website?

In short, it's impossible.

**Enabling multiple custom domains for a single storage account is planned for the coming year.** You can vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/955579-enable-multiple-custom-domains-for-storage-account) to promote this feature to be achieved.